# apxs2 is missing so I can't install Apache mod x-sendfile

Tags: centos, centos5, apache-2.2

I have a CentOS 5.8 server with Apache2.4 and I want to install mod x-sendfile.

I've uploaded the c file to the server and according to the instructions I should run:

```
apxs2 -cia mod_xsendfile.c
```

I tried that but it seems that I don't have apxs2. I do have apxs under /usr/sbin/apxs.

What should I do? should I use apxs or should I get somehow apxs2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMIIW
How do you install apache 2.4 ?, as default Centos 5 using apache 2.2, if you install httpd-devel via YUM/RPM you would see /usr/bin/apxs binary (http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/6/idpl/18132345/dir/centos_5/com/httpd-devel-2.2.3-65.el5.centos.i386.rpm).

if you're compile from source, the apxs should be installed on $PREFIX/bin/apxs. some distribution (like ubuntu/debian), you're able to install httpd v1 and httpd v2, maybe it's use to differentiate between apache (apxs) and apache2 (apxs2).

if you're sure the apxs comes from httpd version that you use, just use apxs instead.

Comment: Just a note to say that to install httpd-devel via yum it would be:

`yum install httpd-devel`

Comment: Been at this for so long, totally saved me with the $PREFIX/bin/apxs.... thanks! And @DaveG, yum install httpd-devel for Centos 6 only installed stuff for httpd 2.2 not 2.4.